# redirect to a new screen from browser

Tags: android

I am using epi twitter to show tweets in my application. My first activity has a login button.
If I click the login button it opens the browser and then I login and it again redirects back to my application.
what I want to do is to start a new activity i.e open up a new screen and display the tweets as soon as the browser redirects , but I have to click on the login button again to go to the next screen.
I used on resume function but it dint help.

Comment: Does it hit the onResume? A simple code example would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not start your second activity immediately from the click of your login button with an extra set in the intent to indicate a login is required. In your second activity , if the"login" extra is set in the intent then launch the browser immediately. When the browser returns, your second activity will be the one displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!! needed to edit the manifest with two things

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

and

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
                <data android:scheme="login"/>
```